# How USB automount works internally in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, usb-storage, ubuntu-18.04, automount

I just want to understand how USB automount works in Ubuntu especially in 18.04. When an USB drive is connected to USB port what all things happen and what utilities or scripts or udev rules(probably) are responsible for mounting/unmounting and where are they located?

Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

These are great introductions

https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/cha-udev.html

https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev

Question has already been answered excellently [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/551047/40896)